# Copy data to new-added worksheets based on selection

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that adds new worksheets based on a range of cells in another worksheet. The code adds up to 10 worksheets and it will name them after the data written in cells. For example:
I might have the following data in my "VG-Class" worksheet:

Cell U2: 1851-A3 --------- Cell U3: 1736-A9 ------ Cell U4: 2171-A7

So the macro will create 3 new worksheets with the names 1851-A3, 1736-A9 and 2171-A7. This is my code:

```
Private CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim numLines As Integer
i = 0
lRow = Worksheets("V-Class GC").Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cel In Worksheets("V-Class GC").Range("U2:U" & lRow)
    If shtNameChk(cel.Value) = False Then
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = cel.Value
    cel.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cel.Offset(0, -1), Address:="", _
    SubAddress:=ws.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=cel.Offset(0, -2).Value & ", " & cel.Offset(0, -3).Value
    i = i + 1
    End If
Next
Worksheets("V-Class GC").Select
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is to populate each one of these new worksheets based on the data from another worksheet called "Information". The new created worksheet "1851-A3" has associated a model, package, reference and price in a list with more codes. I'll use a VLOOKUP to find and place these values. However, I don't know how to make a reference between the name of my worksheets and the codes in this list so the macro can find and place the information corresponding to every code/worksheet name. It's like a report generator.

[Look at this image if you want to see graphically what I mean:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sufoI.jpg)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put this stuff at the top of your macro:

```
Dim wInfo As Worksheet
Dim x as Long
Set wInfo = Sheets("Information")
```

Then put this right before your `End If`

```
'check if model # is found in Col D of Information
If Application.CountIf(wInfo.Columns(4), ws.Name) Then

    'copy headers
    wInfo.Range("D1:H1").Copy ws.Range("D1")

    'look for matching model # and copy data if match
    For x = 1 To wInfo.Cells(wInfo.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If wInfo.Cells(x, 4).Value = ws.Name Then wInfo.Range("D" & x & ":" & "H" & x).Copy ws.Cells(Application.CountA(ws.Columns(4)) + 1, 4)
    Next x
End If
```

In the sample data you provided, it looked like there was only info to be copied over between columns D and H, so that's what I based this answer on. It copies the values from D to H on the Information sheet to D to H on the new worksheet.